# Magento - List a product collection without the foreach

Tags: magento, collections, product

I have a product collection loaded with 6 products. I need to list these products without the foreach, because each product have a different layout structure.
How can I call each product outside the foreach?

My code is:

```
<?php

  $produtos = array(1115,1105,1019,1017,1013,1011);
  $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
  $_productCollection = clone $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
  $_productCollection->clear()
                     ->addIdFilter($produtos)
                     ->load();
  $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
```

The variable $produtos is an array with the product IDs that I want in the collection

Then, i need to set variables for each product attribute. Im doing like this:

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php 
        if($_product->getId() == $produtos[0]){
            $productName1 = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); 
            $productImage1 = '<img border="0" src=".'echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(143,215);'." />';
            $precoCru1 = $_product->getFinalPrice(); $productPrice1 = Mage::helper('core')->currency($precoCru1, true, false);
            $productUrl1 = $_product->getProductUrl();
        }

        elseif($_product->getId() == $produtos[1]){
            $productName2 = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); 
            $productImage2 = '<img border="0" src=".'echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(143,215);'." />';
            $precoCru2 = $_product->getFinalPrice(); $productPrice1 = Mage::helper('core')->currency($precoCru1, true, false);
            $productUrl2 = $_product->getProductUrl();                      
        }
    ?>                  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The product name, url and price are working, but the image not. When I echo each product image, it gave me the same URL

Answer (score 3):

You can't avoid the `foreach` entirely, because that's not how programing works, but give this a try

```
$array = array();
$c=1;
foreach($product_collection as $product)
{
    $array['product_'.$c] = $product;
    $c++;
}
```

and you'll be able to reference each individual product

```
var_dump($array['product_1']->getData());
var_dump($array['product_2']->getData());
```

If you **really** want to confuse the next programmer, try the above code, but then do this

```
extract($array);
var_dump($product_1->getData());
```

The `extract` function will export each key of the array as a PHP variable.

Comment: Alan, thanks for your answer, but I was not able to do it. I edited my question with more information. Can you help me again?

Comment: @Paulo Read the answer.  The idea is you run through the for each loop and load up an array with products.  Then, OUTSIDE the loop you can reference them individually by number.

Comment: Alan, I read your answer but I could not understand how to, for example, call the product image and resizes it. Could you give me this example, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the items and then use them as a regular array and refer to the elements by their index:

```
$items = $collection->getItems();
$first = $items[0];
$second = $items[1];
```

or if you need just the first one:

```
$first = $collection->getFirstItem();
```

Have a look at lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php

Comment: How can I, for example, call the product image and resizes it?

Comment: @Paulo try using thumbnail instead of small_image, your product might not have a small_image. So that would be $src = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(143,215);